# Отловить исключение при подключении статической dll при пуске программы

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Just
{

static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        InstantiateMyTypeFail(currentDomain);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Main());

    }

    private static void InstantiateMyTypeFail(AppDomain domain)
    {
        string paths = domain.BaseDirectory + "alias.dll";
        if (!File.Exists(paths))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Запуск программы не возможен без:\nalias.dll");
            Environment.Exit(0xBADF00D);
        }
    }
}
```

}

В этом коде проверяется наличие dll, и завершается работа программы при ее отсутствии(с сообщением), а если dll повреждена происходит аварийное завершение.
Как сделать проверку на: вызывает dll ошибку в программе и обработать ее.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42968541

Comment: Спасибо, исчерпывающий ответ!